# Replace AWORD or BWORD with CWORD in sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

So I have a list of random websites of the following kind:

```
   rapido21655bonk.a.sweetpotato.net
   rapido26230bonk.a.sourpotato.net
   rapido29926bonk.b.sourpotato.net
   rapido29926bonk.b.sweetpotato.net
   rapido30179bonk.a.sweetpotato.net
   rapido30648bonk.b.sourpotato.net
   rapido30761bonk.c.sweetpotato.net
```

Now I need a sed string to only leave the number, and take everything else out. What I did was:
`sed s/rapido//` to get rid of the first part of it, but for the second part, I could use sed twice to get rid of them both, but I want to know if I can use some kind of `or` logic to remove both in one sed. I know I can use sed to match `a or b or c` using `[abc]` but I want something like that for whole words. So what I did after this was:

`sed s/rapido//|sed s/bonk.[abc].sweetpotato.net//` and then I would put another one with just sourpotato.net, but I can't seem to do the following:

`sed s/rapido//|sed s/bonk.[abc].(sweet|sour)potato.net//`
This doesn't work. It gives me this:
`-bash: syntax error near unexpected token`('`

Only replacing the number doesn't not work, because sometimes I might get stuff like `rapido22452boonkers.red` which I would want to still have there. I would want to ONLY remove the 2 alternatives `sweetpotato.net` OR `sourpotato.net`.

```
[111@111 ~]$ sed s/rapido// sedster|sed 's/bonk.[abc].(sweetpotato|sourpotato).net//'
   21655bonk.a.sweetpotato.net
   26230bonk.a.sourpotato.net
   29926bonk.b.sourpotato.net
   29926bonk.b.sweetpotato.net
   30179bonk.a.sweetpotato.net
   30648bonk.b.sourpotato.net
   30761bonk.c.sweetpotato.net
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
sed -r 's/([^0-9]*)([0-9]*)([^0-9]*)/\2/g'
```

you can keep only the number in the middle. This only works with extended regular expressions, so you need the `-r` option to `sed`.

Actually, it suffices to use

```
sed -r 's/([^0-9]*)([0-9]*)(.*)/\2/g'
```

This uses the function of referencing parts of the expression with `\1`, `\2`, ... You then have to use parentheses `(...)` around the part of your expression you want to reference. In the above code, the second part `([0-9]*)` will match the number in the middle, and you can refer to this by `\2`.

**Edit:** As terdon pointed out, we don't need to capture the initial part since we don't use it again. So

```
sed -n -r 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1/p'
```

is enough.

To summarize, the command above keeps only the **first** number in your input line.

Comment: I don't understand this part of it though `/\2/`, I want it replaced with nothing, like `//`

Comment: @sweetsourpotato It works, just try it, for example `echo ab234bc | sed -r 's/([^0-9]*)([0-9]*)(.*)/\2/g'`

Comment: There's no reason to capture the groups you won't be using, but you do need `+` or `[0-9][0-9]*` so it won't match when there are no numbers. You also don't want the `g` there as far as I can tell. This should be enough: `sed -r 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]+)(.*)/\1/'`.

Comment: What I don't understand is why I get a syntax error if I use (word1|word2)

Comment: @sweetsourpotato we can't help you if you don't show your syntax error. If you used the command from your updated question, the error is because you're not quoting the sed pattern. Note how both this answer and my own have `sed 'blah blah'` and not just `sed blah blah`.

Comment: Yes sorry it was the lack of quotes, but now I have a different problem, I edited my initial question because I can't fit it here

Comment: @terdon: Thanks for reminding me. By the way, my first approach was, accidentally, `sed -r 's/([^0-9]*)([0-9])([^0-9]*)/\2/g'` (without the `*` for the middle part), and strangly, it worked.

Comment: Ok so far everything works EXCEPT for one thing: if I do [abc] it take a or b or c, but how do I make it so that it would take a or b or c OR NOTHING? Because sometimes the address doesn't have the a, or b or c there, and then it doesn't match it.
Nevermind I found it, I had to put `[abc]{0,1}`. Thanks for the help everybody!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to extract the numbers, you can do this with GNU `grep`:

```
$ grep -oP '\d+' file
21655
26230
29926
29926
30179
30648
30761
```

Or, portably with perl:

```
$ perl -pe 's/[^\d\n]+//g' file
21655
26230
29926
29926
30179
30648
30761
```

Or `sed`:

```
$ sed -nE 's/[^0-9]+//gp' file
21655
26230
29926
29926
30179
30648
30761
```

If you need something more specific to your input data, you can try:

```
$ sed -nE 's/.*rapido([0-9]+)bonk\..\.(sweet|sour)potato.net.*/\1/p' file
21655
26230
29926
29926
30179
30648
30761
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but only replacing the number doesn't help me, because sometimes I might get stuff like `rapido22452boonkers.red` which I would want to still have there. I would want to ONLY remove the 2 alternatives `sweetpotato.net` OR `sourpotato.net`.

Comment: @sweetsourpotato see update. But please remember to make that sort of thing clear when asking a question. Ideally, you need to ask showing an example of your input data that covers all possible cases and the output you want from it.

Comment: Thank you, but what does this do? `/\1/p` I mean, using (word1|word2) gave me a bash error, so will that help?

Comment: @sweetsourpotato what error? Did you use the _exact_ command? The `\1` refers to the 1st [_captured group_](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html), the `([0-9]+)`, so it will replace the entire match with what was captured. The `p` means "only print if the substitution was successful" so any lines not matching the pattern will be skipped (the `-n` means "don't print unless I tell you to"). Your question suggested you only want the numbers, so I wanted to skip any lines that didn't match. If that's not what you want, remove the `-n` and `-p` and edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt

```
sed s/rapido// | sed s/bonk.[abc](sweet|sour)potato.net//
```

was actually pretty close, but you made two mistakes. The first is that you didn't put the command inside quotes, so `bash` interpreted the special characters "(" and "|". (The fact that you got a bash error message should have tipped you off to this).

The second mistake is more subtle. `Sed` and `grep` use *basic* regular expressions, in which only a few characters ( **. * ^ $ [ ]** ) have special meaning. If you want to use *extended* regex operators ( **| () {}** ), you need to precede them with a backslash. So here's what your command should have looked like:

```
sed < t 's/rapido//' | sed 's/bonk.[abc].\(sweet\|sour\)potato.net//'
```

and since `sed` can handle multiple commands in one run, you can simplify this to

```
sed < t 's/rapido//; s/bonk.[abc].\(sweet\|sour\)potato.net//'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '/\.\([abc]\.\)\{0,1\}\(sweet\|sour\)potato\.net$/s/[^0-9]//g'
```

Select the lines to be edited and then remove the nondigits from those.

To make it llook less cluttered, use the `-r` option of sed:

```
 sed -re '/[.]([abc][.])?(sweet|sour)potato\.net$/ s/[^0-9]//g'
```

Comment: Beware `\|` and `-r` are GNUisms and what `[0-9]` matches is unspecified outside the POSIX/C locale (and sometimes random in practice depending on the sed/libc/gnulib implementation/version and locale)

Answer (score 0):

To remove everything but the numbers, [`tr`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html) is a solution:

```
x='21655bonk.a.sweetpotato.net
   26230bonk.a.sourpotato.net
   29926bonk.b.sourpotato.net
   29926bonk.b.sweetpotato.net
   30179bonk.a.sweetpotato.net
   30648bonk.b.sourpotato.net
   30761bonk.c.sweetpotato.net'
printf '%s\n' "$x" | tr -d '[:alpha:].' 
21655 26230 29926 29926 30179 30648 30761
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' "$x" | tr -cd '0-9 '
```

Comment: The first one preserves the newline characters, so you shouldn't be getting that output.

Comment: Beware what 0-9 matches is unspecified outside the POSIX/C locale.  You may prefer `tr -cd '0123456789 '` or `tr -cd '[:digit:] '`